# How to get the just the Content inside an XElement

Tags: .net, xml, linq, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

How do I use linq2sql to get a node that contains any matching content excluding any nested elements.

In other words, I have an XElement containing

```
<div>
  <div>
    <p>
      The Content
    </p>
    <p> 
      Some other content
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to get that first <p> element based on the fact that its contents when Trimmed are exactly "The Content"

Answer (score 0):

This might be slow for very large XML files, so usefulness depends on your task.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication9
{
    using System.Xml.Linq;
    using System.Linq;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XElement xx = XElement.Parse(@"<div>
  <div>
    <p>
      The Content
    </p>
    <p> 
      Some other content
    </p>
  </div>
</div>");
            XNode node = xx
                .DescendantNodesAndSelf()
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.ToString().Trim() == "The Content");

            if (node != null)
            {
                XElement el = node.Parent;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I got a similar hackaround going (I first filter out the ones with any Elements) but I wonder what the correct way of doing this is.